# What is swift's equivalent of a Pthread semaphore or a spin lock?

Tags: ios, multithreading, swift, semaphore

**Background**

I am currently using *objc_sync_enter/exit* pairs to manage locks:

```
func sync(lock: AnyObject, closure: () -> ())
{
    objc_sync_enter(lock)
    closure()
    objc_sync_exit(lock)
}

func sync<T>(lock: AnyObject, closure: () -> T ) -> T
{
    var t : T
    objc_sync_enter(lock)
    t = closure()
    objc_sync_exit(lock)
    return t
}
```

I can use these mechanisms to update a *semaphore* where I count down the tasks that I need to complete.

Now, in a separate thread, I would like to **wait** until my semaphore reaches zero, perhaps using something like a pthread semaphore or some kind of cheap/light spin lock?

```
var semaphore = 2  // ->0 using sync() when all preparation is complete
fun call_me_when_semaphore_becomes_zero() { }
```

**Question**

*How can I wait for a boolean condition using swift/iOS synchronization mechanisms?*

It would be nice if the interface looked something like this:

```
// implementation
func sync_wait(lock: AnyObject, condition: (()->Bool), closure: (() -> ()))
{
    // NEED HELP HERE -------------------------------------------------------
    // using lock, wait until condition becomes true, and then call closure
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------
}

// call
sync_wait( semaphore, condition: { semaphore==0 }, closure: { call_me_when_semaphore_becomes_zero() } )
```

Comment: Can you use `dispatch_semaphore_create` and `dispatch_semaphore_wait`?

Comment: @AaronBrager perhaps `dispatch_group_wait` will more concisely do what I am looking for - ty for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: NP. Not sure how much iOS stuff you've done, but a more common pattern in iOS is for A to inform B when it's done, rather than for B to wait for A to finish something. This is typically done with the delegation or notification patterns, or by passing around completion handlers.

Comment: @AaronBrager thx for the tip - in this case, I need to do C after both A and B (both async) are done.

Comment: You may want to also look at NSOperationQueue. A, B, and C can be separate operations and C can be dependent on the completion of A and B. (NSOperationQueue is an easy-to-use wrapper around grand central dispatch.)

Comment: @AaronBrager thx again!  I was looking exactly for a job queue when you posted - will check out NSOperationQueue...